# Which API response format to choose if there are json and text?

Tags: python, json, api, text

I'm coding an API library in Python, I always chose **json** before as the response format but this API provides **text** and **json** formats, I'm not asking which one is easier or better, I want to know the advantages and the disadvantages of using both as I only worked with json before.

I thought about using **text** format, it's very easy to parse but the only thing I thought about was the nested elements, but after checking the example they're separated with underscores `_` for example:

```
name=VALUE
lastname=VALUE
age=VALUE
contact_email=VALUE
contact_phone=VALUE
contact_mobile=VALUE
```

same **json** response:

```
{
    "name": "VALUE",
    "lastname": "VALUE",
    "age": "VALUE",
    "contact": {
        "email": "VALUE",
        "phone": "VALUE",
        "mobile": "VALUE"
    }
}
```

So is there any advantages or disadvantages of using **text** over **json** or the other way around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the main advantages of json over text would be:

- DRY - there are third party libs for json processing which are quite performant
- The parsed json ends up being a dict, which you cam refer by keys easily

For the text variant, there is the `.ini` format, which could offer something aling the lines of structure, although the format you described above is not really designed for nested fields and structures.

I'd also look at who's consuming your API. E.g. if it's a web app, then json is the accepted format. if your consumer is something else which is more comfortable with the text format...

Answer (score 1):

JSON can be easier as you can use the json library.

The return you've shown there can be put into a dictionary with the line:

```
import json
json.loads(return_string)
```

Much easier to parse than the text!